# C++ Deleting Class Member Char*

Tags: c++, char, delete-operator

I have a simple class called myString that holds a `char*` as a private member. No matter what I do, I can't seem to delete it.

```
class myString
{
public:
  myString():letters( "This is a string" ){}
  ~myString()
  {
    delete []letters;
  }
private:
  char* letters;
}
```

I have tried `delete letters`, `delete[] letters`, etc but I always receive an error. I used to debugger, and letters is always initialized to a string/points to a string, and the debugger always crashes on the delete line.

Answer (score 3):

`letters` points to a string literal, that is to say every instance of `myString` points to the same data in your loaded program executable.

You cannot delete a string literal, nor do you need to.

Comment: Why can I not/ need not to delete a string literal? Rather is it something that will just be cleaned up when it falls out of scope?

Comment: @Theopile: string literals have static storage duration -- they exist until the program exits.

Answer (score 3):

Please be aware:

- A pointer is never allocated automatically.
- "Hello Word" has the type const char[11] (the conversion is const char* not char*)
- Assigning const char* to a char* is no good.
- You can only delete/delete[] a pointer if that pointer got it's value from new/new[] before.

Comment: What is the short hand assignment letters( "This is a string" ) doing? is it creating a string literal and pointing letters to the address of T? How would I use the short hand to assign a dynamic char array even though they would all say "This is a string"?

Comment: @Theopile Use memcopy or strcpy to move the data to the right spot, after you allocated memory for the array.  Since you are using C++ why not std::string?

Comment: @Theopile char* = const char* (which is the "This is a string") is deprecated in C++.

Comment: `"Hello Word"` has type `const char[11]`, not `const char*`.

Answer (score 2):

First allocated memory then try to delete, you're attempting to delete a string literal.

```
class myString
{
public:
  myString() {letters= new char [25]; /* Copying code */}
  ~myString()
  {
    delete []letters;
  }
private:
  char* letters;
}
```

Comment: From reading the other comments, how would I assign "This is a string" so that it is not a string literal?

Comment: @Theopile may be something like this `myString() {letters= new char [25]; strcpy(letters,"This is a string");}`

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want to have a *copy* of the string, perhaps so you can modify it later. C++ won't make the string buffer for you, you have to do that yourself.

```
myString()
{
    letters = new char[MAX_STRING_LEN];
    strcpy(letters, "This is a string");
}
```

Naturally it would be better to use `std::string` rather than a dynamically allocated character buffer, but I'll assume you have your reasons.